# VC++ using fp:fast causes wrong (not just inaccurate) results - is this a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, visual-studio-2017, compiler-bug

I've installed the latest VS2017 update (15.4.4), and when compiling our projects the unit tests started failing.
It seems that the problem happens in some scenarios when using optimizations (/O2) and fast model for floating point (/fp:fast).
This problem did not happen with a previous compiler (VS2017 update 15.2).

Here's a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>

const float FACTOR = 0.01745329251994329576923690768489f;

unsigned long long hoursToMicrosecs(int hours)
{
    return hours * 3600 * 1000000LL;
}

float degToRad(float deg)
{
    return deg * FACTOR;
}

float f(int u1, int u2)
{
    float percent = ((u1 - u2) / 1000.0f) / (hoursToMicrosecs(24) / 1000000.0f);
    return degToRad(percent * 360);
}

int main()
{   
    auto result = f(3600000, 35063681);
    std::cout << result << '\n';
    return (result > -3.0f) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

`result` should be -2.2881, but the output is actually -394.868, which is not just inaccurate.

It works if I do any of the following:

- Remove optimizations
- Change to fp:precise
- Return to the previous compiler (15.2)

Looking at the disassembly shows us that the compiler tried doing something nice for us - it just calculated the whole thing at compile time and replaced with a single number.

The optimized code is just a one-liner:

```
011F1000  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [__real@c3c56f11 (011F2118h)]
```

My question is: Is this a compiler bug (which I should report) or is it wrong usage of fp:fast?

Comment: The optimized code just loads the precomputed result. What's more interesting is that both gcc and clang store and load that as a `double`, not as a `float`. Maybe `/fp:fast` causes the precomputation to be stored as `double`, but then it gets loaded as `float`? Anyways, does look like a bug.

Comment: Interesting idea. I checked if converting to double the 8 bytes starting at this address (0x011F2118) or 4 bytes before that is similar to the expected result, and no. So I guess the correct result is not stored as a double there. Thanks for the thought.

Comment: (a) What is the size of `int` and `unsigned long long`? (b) Peel off the calculations in reverse chronological order: In degToRad, change `return deg * FACTOR` to `return deg`. Are the optimized and non-optimized results still different? Then remove the `/ 1000000.0f` and test. Then remove `/ hoursToMicrosecs(24)` and test. (If the failure is there, put it back and take apart the calculations within it.) Continue in this vein. One of these steps will get you to a point where the optimized and non-optimized results are the same, and that will give you a clue where something went astray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing here. I think I found the issue: `hoursToMicroseconds(24)` is overflowing. It shouldn't, as the expression should be converted to `unsigned long long` before the multiplication with `1000000LL`. But if you cast that result back to an `unsigned int`, you'll get 500654080 rather than 86400000000. So the whole calculation eventually boils down to -394.868.

I would definitely say this is a compiler bug. It seems you can circumvent it by casting the `unsigned long long` result to `double` first.

**EDIT**

You know what else is funny? If you make all your functions `constexpr`, and also declare `result` as `constexpr` in `main()`, it *will* produce the right result. So there are apparently two separate code paths in the compiler that can compute the value at compile time, and one of them is broken.

Comment: Excellent analysis! I'll report this to MS and add a link here.
Regarding a workaround - I changed the compilation flag in all my projects to fp:precise, since there maybe other places in which it happens, is just modifying this one function might not be enough.

Comment: Reported at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155625/c-compiler-bug-when-using-fpfast-and-o2.html